# python-for-android fails installing SDK

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy

i'm new to kivy and python-for-android i followed the instructions in  [here](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer)  but i face a problem using python-for-android

when i run `buildozer android release` the output is:

```
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Install platform
# Apache ANT found at /home/kasra/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /home/kasra/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20
# Android NDK found at /home/kasra/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c
# Check application requirements
# Check garden requirements
# Compile platform
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=app --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=/home/kasra/Desktop/kivy/first_one :|/.buildozer/android/platform/build
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# If the error is not obvious, please raise the log_level to 2
# and retry the latest command.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

and when i run `/usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=app --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=/home/kasra/Desktop/kivy/first_one :|/.buildozer/android/platform/build`

i face:

```
[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    Found possible SDK dirs in buildozer dir: android-sdk-20
[INFO]:    Will attempt to use SDK at /home/kasra/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20
[WARNING]: This SDK lookup is intended for debug only, if you use python-for-android much you should probably maintain your own SDK download.
[INFO]:    Android API target was not set manually, using the default of 15
[INFO]:    Available Android APIs are (19)
[WARNING]: Requested API target 15 is not available, install it with the SDK android tool.
[WARNING]: Exiting.
```

can someone help please? :/

Comment: Edit your *buildozer.spec* file and replace *log_level* from 1 with *2*. Run with *buildozer android debug*

Comment: @ikolim still same problem :/

Comment: Could you share with us the error from the full log in a zip file?

Comment: Were you able to have a successful build with *buildozer android debug*?

Comment: @ikolim how should i send u file in here ???    i send them to ur email :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

the problem is that i didnt use sudo permission 
`sudo buildozer android debug`