# Buildozer failed to compile the platform after checking garden requirements

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

I am trying to make an Android app for a program I wrote in Python 3.

I have worked and cleared several problems before this but I have no idea what is causing the issue at this point. If there is any additional information you would need to help me fix this I will be more than happy to add it.

```
eddie@eddie-VirtualBox:~$ buildozer android debug deploy run
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.19.0.5 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /usr/local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Run "/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install -q --user 'appdirs' 'colorama>=0.3.3' 'jinja2' 'six'"
# Cwd None
# Apache ANT found at /home/eddie/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /home/eddie/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20
# Android NDK found at /home/eddie/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c
# Check application requirements
# Check garden requirements
# Compile platform
# Run '/usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=What\'s for Dinner? --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements =python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/eddie/.buildozer/android/platform/build"'
# Cwd /home/eddie/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=What's for Dinner? --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/eddie/.buildozer/android/platform/build"
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you see is caused by an opening quote that is not matched with a closing one.

Most command line syntax requires you to escape any spaces you use.
In Unix systems, if a file is called "Stack Overflow.txt", to access it you would need to write

```
nano Stack\ Overflow.txt
```

or alternatively:

```
nano "Stack Overflow.txt"
```

So in your case I am assuming in this line

```
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=What's for Dinner? --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/eddie/.buildozer/android/platform/build"
```

the spaces in What\'s for Dinner? are probably breaking the string, causing a quote to go unmatched. I do not know where the String comes from. Could you tell me? Because the quote is supposedly escaped, but the spaces are not.

Comment: The What's for Dinner? Is the name of the program i made. I adding the \ to escape the ' and ran the code again and got another error. `[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi-v7a`
`[INFO]:    Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI`
`[INFO]:    Available Android APIs are ()`
`[WARNING]: Requested API target 19 is not available, install it with the SDK android tool.`
`[WARNING]: Exiting.`

Comment: That means you don't have Android platforms installed. Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49675018/python-for-android-fails-installing-sdk) helpful?

Comment: I thought that was what the ndk and sdk tools where. I have both of those unless i didn't set something up right.